# How can I convert a binary to a decimal without using a loop?

Tags: matlab, binary, decimal

I have a 12-bit binary that I need to convert to a decimal. For example:

```
A = [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0];
```

Bit 1 is the most significant bit, Bit 12 is the least significant bit.

Comment: Related: [How to convert list of binary values to int32 type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52593070/52738)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Note:** This answer applies primarily to unsigned data types. For converting to signed types, a few extra steps are necessary, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52594267/52738).

---

The [`bin2dec`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bin2dec.html) function is one option, but requires you to change the vector to a string first. `bin2dec` can also be slow compared to computing the number yourself. Here's a solution that's about 75 times faster:

```
>> A = [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0];
>> B = sum(A.*2.^(numel(A)-1:-1:0))

B =

        1548
```

To explain, `A` is multiplied element-wise by a vector of powers of 2, with the exponents ranging from `numel(A)-1` down to `0`. The resulting vector is then summed to give the integer represented by the binary pattern of zeroes and ones, with the first element in the array being considered the most significant bit. If you want the first element to be considered the least significant bit, you can do the following:

```
>> B = sum(A.*2.^(0:numel(A)-1))

B =

        774
```

**Update:** You may be able to squeeze even a little more speed out of MATLAB by using [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get the indices of the ones (avoiding the element-wise multiplication and potentially reducing the number of exponent calculations needed) and using the [`pow2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pow2.html) function instead of `2.^...`:

```
B = sum(pow2(find(flip(A))-1));  % Most significant bit first
B = sum(pow2(find(A)-1));        % Least significant bit first
```

**Extending the solution to matrices...**

If you have a lot of binary vectors you want to convert to integers, the above solution can easily be modified to convert all the values with one matrix operation. Suppose `A` is an N-by-12 matrix, with one binary vector per row. The following will convert them all to an N-by-1 vector of integer values:

```
B = A*(2.^(size(A, 2)-1:-1:0)).';  % Most significant bit first
B = A*(2.^(0:size(A, 2)-1)).';     % Least significant bit first
```

Also note that all of the above solutions automatically determine the number of bits in your vector by looking at the number of columns in `A`.

Comment: This is somewhat similar to what **bin2dec** function does except using **pow2**, in addition to removing spaces from string and converting it to number using `s-'0'`

Answer (score 4):

[Dominic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552966/converting-binary-to-decimal-without-using-loop/1552981#1552981)'s answer assumes you have access to the *Data Acquisition toolbox*. If not use **bin2dec**:

```
A = [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0];
bin2dec( sprintf('%d',A) )
```

or (in reverse)

```
A = [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0];
bin2dec( sprintf('%d',A(end:-1:1)) )
```

depending on what you intend to be bit 1 and 12!

Answer (score 2):

If the MSB is right-most (I'm not sure what you mean by Bit 1, sorry if that seems stupid):

Try:

```
binvec2dec(A)
```

Output should be:

```
 ans =
   774
```

If the MSB is left-most, use `fliplr(A)` first.