# How do I convert a large array of 8 bit binary values in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, binary, type-conversion

This is a follow-up question to [another SO question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544456/faster-version-of-dec2bin-function-for-converting-many-elements).

I have a large array of 8 bit binary values that I want to convert back to uint8.

I have used Amro's lookupTable solution from the previous question. Now I want to do the reverse. I wanted to do a lookup table but sadly I am unable to.

What I managed to do is the following:

```
temp = ones([(TotalPixel),1], 'uint8');

for iter2 = 1 : TotalPixel,
     temp(iter2,1) = sum(Data(iter2,1:8).*2.^(7:-1:0));   
end
```

But the for loop is too slow as it takes 2 seconds to convert a [76800 x 1] array. Is there a better/faster way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
temp = uint8(Data*(2.^(7:-1:0))');
```

Note that this answer is basically the same as [an edit I made to an answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552966/converting-binary-to-decimal-without-using-loop/1554876#1554876) to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552966/converting-binary-to-decimal-without-using-loop) you asked. You had asked there about just converting a single row of 12-bit values, but I had added an extra discussion of how you would extend it to converting multiple values at once using a [matrix multiply](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/mtimes.html). The difference between that answer and this is simply the number of bits and the inclusion of [UINT8](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/uint8.html) to change the variable type.