# Alternate method for bin2dec function

Tags: matlab

i m looking for an alternate method for bin2dec conversion to speed up my code.bin2dec functions takes 2.5 to 3 sec as run time.Is there any solution.
Here is my code:

```
img = imread('cameraman.tif');
D1=256;D2=256;
img = dec2bin(img(:)).';
I   = reshape(permute(reshape(imgD, 8, [], D2), [2,1,3]), D1, D2 * 8);
```

(Processing)

```
a1{D1,D2} = [];
for i=1:1:D1
    for j=1:1:D2
        a1{i,j,1}=I(i,:,j); 
    end
end
C1 = bin2dec(a1);
```

Is there anyway to speed up the `bin2dec` function and make the running time under 0.2 seconds or even better as every miliseconds counts for my application?

Comment: Consider formatting your question neatly.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate, since [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1554876/52738) addresses this issue exactly.