# How to convert list of binary values to int32 type?

Tags: matlab, binary, type-conversion, int32

I have a list of binary numbers in little-endian format in MATLAB workspace, and I want to convert them to int32.  `a` is a double vector of zeroes and ones, like so:

```
a = [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1   1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0   0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0   1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0];
```

`int32(a)` gives me a row vector of the 32 binary values without converting it to 32 bit integer.

Comment: Is `a` a logical or character vector?

Comment: its a double vector, I read it in from a file as fread(f,'ubit1'). p.s I am not using 'int32' because I am removing certain parts of the file by a bit pattern.

Comment: You can also calculate the number directly, e.g. by defining once a vector of the binary weights and then multiply it by your vector. If the vector is however in e.g. 2's complement, you can extend by the definition

Comment: mantanj makes a good point. How should we interpret the [format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) (one's complement, two's complement, offset binary)?

Comment: The byte ordering is like this. 
[2...1][4...3][6...5][8...7].   8 being the most significant bit and 1 being the least significant bit. [ ] is one byte and ... indicate the 6 other bits in that byte. And if 8 is 0, the number is positive, if 1 its negative. Thank you for suggestion, I will create a vector with the weights and multiply it.

Comment: Related: [How can I convert a binary to a decimal without using a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1552966/52738)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [solutions from this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1552966/52738) (which is specific to unsigned integers) can be modified to handle a signed integer. The easiest approach would be to convert the output from there to [`uint32`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint32.html), then convert to [`int32`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int32.html) using [`typecast`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html). Building on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1554876/52738):

```
>> a = [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0];
>> b = typecast(uint32(sum(pow2(find(a)-1))), 'int32')

b =

  int32

   521688984
```

If you know the [specific representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) used for the bit pattern (my guess would be [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two's_complement)), you could avoid using `typecast` by accounting for the sign bit and [complement](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitcmp.html) directly in the calculations.

If `a` is an N-by-32 matrix, you can simply replace the `sum(...)` with the vectorized calculations from the linked solution:

```
b = typecast(uint32(a*(2.^(0:size(a, 2)-1)).'), 'int32');
```

Comment: Thank you it works. how do i apply it to each row of a matrix, like n by 32 matrix?